# Range query - Data modeling for time series in CQL Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I have a table like this:

> CREATE TABLE test (   partitionkey text,   rowkey text, date
>   timestamp,  policyid text,  policyname text, primary key
>   (partitionkey, rowkey));

with some data:

> partitionkey |    rowkey |    policyid |    policyname |  date
>
> ```
>      p1 |   r1 |    pl1 |  plicy1 | 2007-01-02 00:00:00+0000
>      p1 |   r2 |    pl2 |  plicy2 | 2007-01-03 00:00:00+0000
>      p2 |   r3 |    pl3 |  plicy3 | 2008-01-03 00:00:00+0000
> ```

I want to be able to find:

```
1/ data from a particular partition key
2/ data from a particular partition key & rowkey
3/ Range query on date given a partitionkey
```

1/ and 2/ are trivial:

> select * from test where partitionkey='p1';
>
> partitionkey | rowkey | policyid | policyname | range
>
> ```
>     p1 |     r1 |      pl1 |     plicy1 | 2007-01-02 00:00:00+0000
>     p1 |     r2 |      pl2 |     plicy2 | 2007-01-03 00:00:00+0000
> ```

but what about 3/? 
Even with an index it doesnt work:

> create index i1 on test (date);
>
> select * from test where partitionkey='p1' and date =
>   '2007-01-02';
>
> partitionkey | rowkey | policyid | policyname | date
>
> ```
>   p1 |  r1 |   pl1   plicy1 | 2007-01-02 00:00:00+0000
> ```
>
> but
>
> select * from test where partitionkey='p1' and
>   date > '2007-01-02';
>
> Bad Request: No indexed columns present in
>   by-columns clause with Equal operator

Any idea?
thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CREATE TABLE test ( **partitionkey** text, **rowkey** text, date timestamp,
>   policyid text, policyname text, primary key (partitionkey, rowkey));

First of all, you really should use more descriptive column names instead of partitionkey and rowkey (and even date, for that matter).  By looking at those column names, I really can't tell what kind of data this table is supposed to be indexed by.

```
select * from test where partitionkey='p1' and date > '2007-01-02';
```

> Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator

As for this issue, try making your "date" column a part of your primary key.

```
primary key (partitionkey, rowkey, date)
```

Once you do that, I think your date range queries will function appropriately.

For more information on this, check out [DataStax Academy's](https://academy.datastax.com/) (free) course called Java Development With Apache Cassandra.  Session 5, Module 104 discusses how to model time series data and that should help you out.

Comment: Right that works, as long as the query has a 'allow filtering' clause (message _Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING_). Why is this and how does it affect performance ?

Comment: I think you are seeing that warning because your `rowkey` is not specified in that query.  The example I referenced used only the partition key and the date as the primary key...  I suppose you could try defining your rowkey as a part of the partition key `primary key ((partitionkey, rowkey), date)` and see if that helps.

Comment: Sure, but then it requires me to add a clause for 'rowkey' which i dont always have. I guess i'll live with the first solution, thanks.